# ldap3 query group users returns no user data

Tags: python-3.x, ldap3

I'm using below script to retrieve the members of group using ldap3 in python 3.5 but, it's giving me only the group details and no user data.

script :

```
conn.search(search_base='CN=Admins,DC=Server,DC=com', search_filter='(&(objectClass=GROUP)(cn=Admins))' , search_scope=SUBTREE, attributes = ['cn', 'givenName'], size_limit=0)
```

Output :

```
[DN: CN=Admins,OU=UK,DC=SERVER,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2018-11-16T10:34:29.233019

    cn: Admins

]
```